# Optimization of code for speed

Tags: ruby, performance, optimization, primes

It's a prime number sieve, but not Eratosthenes's Sieve.

I feel that it's poorly written because I'm new to programming and Ruby in general. This is only the second program I've written in Ruby, but I'd like to optimize it as best as possible. The problem is I don't have a firm understanding of what I need to change to make it faster, except that I know the program path/data structures aren't ideal - I just don't have a concept to work from to MAKE them ideal

An ideal answer won't necessarily say "change X to Y", but it would be more helpful if it pointed me in the direction of a good resource for this kind of information, or a method by which I can derive information regarding efficiency of different pieces of the program.

```
count = 0
x = 0
$results = Array.new []
inpt = []

class PrimeFun

  def initialize(x, y)

    array1 = (x..y).to_a
    array1.each do |n|

      if PrimeFun.primelogic(n%60, n) == 1
        array1.delete_if { |p| p % n == 0}
        $results << n
      elsif n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5
        $results << n

      end
    end
  end


  def self.primelogic(r, n)

    @prime = case r
      when 1, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 49, 53
        formulaone(n)
      when 7, 19, 31, 43
        formulatwo(n)
      when 11, 23, 47, 59
        formulathree(n)
      else -1

    end  
  end


  def self.formulaone(n)
   @x = 1
   @y = -1

   until 4*(@x**2) >= n
      @y = -@y if Math.sqrt(n-(4*(@x**2))).floor - Math.sqrt(n-(4*(@x**2))) == 0  
     @x += 1

   end
   @y
  end

  def self.formulatwo(n)
    @x = 1
    @y = -1

    until 3*(@x**2) >= n
      @y = -@y if Math.sqrt(n-(3*(@x**2))).floor - Math.sqrt(n-(3*(@x**2))) == 0
      @x += 1

    end
    @y
  end

  def self.formulathree(n)
    @x = 1
    @y = -1

    until 3*(@x**2) >= n
      @y = -@y if Math.sqrt(((@x**2)+n)/3).floor - Math.sqrt(((@x**2)+n)/3) == 0 && @x > @y
      @x += 1

    end
   @y
  end

end


x = STDIN.gets.to_i

while count < x
  inpt << STDIN.gets.chomp
  count += 1
end

inpt.each do |n|
  a = n.split(" ").map { |a| a.to_i }
  PrimeFun.new(a[0], a[1])
  $results << ""
end

puts $results
```

Comment: Take a look at ruby prof - it will tell you where your code is spending time.

Answer (score 5):

You should familiarize yourself with the [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) module included in the Ruby standard library to measure the running time of (different versions of) your methods. I have not run the below code suggestions through Benchmark myself, they are just some quick ideas off the top of my head on how to improve the speed and readability of your code - feel free to benchmark them and report back with the results! :-)

Profiling your code to find the bottlenecks is also a good idea - no point spending hours optimizing parts of your code that is not contributing a large amount to the total run time. Check out the [ruby-prof](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof) gem for a good tool to help you with this.

---

Now for a quick look at your code and some suggestions for improvement.

Without considering the actual algorithm your are using, your first order of business should be to eliminate your code's tendency to recalculate the same values over and over multiple times.

Also, you seem to be using instance variables (@x, @y, etc.) where local variables will do the job nicely. Not to mention your use of class methods which are only being called from within instance methods of the same class. You should turn those into instance methods as well. (These are not really optimization hints, but suggestions on how to improve your Ruby code.)

Take this method as an example:

```
def self.formulaone(n)
  @x = 1
  @y = -1
  until 4*(@x**2) >= n
    @y = -@y if Math.sqrt(n-(4*(@x**2))).floor - Math.sqrt(n-(4*(@x**2))) == 0  
    @x += 1
  end
  @y
end
```

In the loop, you are calculating the expression `4*(@x**2)` *three* times. One is enough, so store the result in a temporary local variable, *fsq*. You are also calculating the square root of the same number two times inside the loop. Again, store the value in a temporary variable *root*, and use that.

```
def formulaone_b(n)
  x = 1
  y = -1
  until (fsq = 4*(x**2)) >= n
    root = Math.sqrt(n - fsq)
    y = -y if root.floor - root == 0
    x += 1
  end
  y
end
```

That should be a good start.

Probably not an optimization, but you can make the code a bit cleaner by calculating the range for x beforehand, then iterate over it using *each*:

```
def formulaone_c(n)
  y = -1
  (1..Math.sqrt(n / 4)).each do |x|
    root = Math.sqrt(n - 4*(x**2))
    y = -y if root.floor == root # See below
  end
  y
end
```

In the above code I have also replaced the comparison `root.floor - root == 0` with the simpler but equivalent comparison `root.floor == root`, removing one unnecessary substraction.

One more idea: instead of calculating `n - 4*(x**2)` for each iteration, you might just gain a tiny bit of speed by noticing that this value will decrease by `x * 8 + 4` every step, so use a helper variable *d* to update the value of the former expression like this:

```
def formulaone_d(n)
  y = -1
  d = n - 4 # Value of n - 4*(x**2) when x = 1
  (1..Math.sqrt(n / 4)).each do |x|
    root = Math.sqrt(d)
    y = -y if root.floor == root
    d -= x * 8 + 4 # Value of n - 4*(x**2) after x increases
  end
  y
end
```

Comment: I finished reading through your analysis and took notes on the various parts - I really appreciate all of the advice and your insights into how I can improve not only the speed of this specific program, but the methods you mentioned to make my code easier to read and understand, and also more standard.

Answer (score 3):

### Correctness

First, your code is not correct:

```
def self.formulathree(n)
  @x = 1
  @y = -1

  until 3*(@x**2) >= n
    @y = -@y if Math.sqrt(((@x**2)+n)/3).floor - Math.sqrt(((@x**2)+n)/3) == 0 && @x > @y
    @x += 1

  end
  @y
end
```

Whether or not `@y` is less than `@x` is immaterial, and it's always true, since `@y = ±1` and when `@x = 1`, `@y = -1 < 1`.

What you are interested in is the number of representations

```
n = 3*a^2 - b^2
```

with integers `a > b > 0`. Now, `a^2 = (n + b^2)/3`, so you want

```
(n + b^2)/3 > b^2
n + b^2 > 3*b^2
n > 2*b^2
```

and not `n > 3*b^2` (`b` stands for `@x` here). For example,

```
143 = 11* 13 = 3*7^2 - 2^2 = 3*8^2 - 7^2
```

but 3*7^2 = 147 > 143, so `@x = 7` wouldn't be considered, so 143 would be deemed prime by `formulathree` and

```
179 = 3*9^2 - 8^2
```

would not be considered prime, although it is, since `3*8^2 = 192 > 179`.

Another problem becomes apparent when you output each considered `n` in `initialize` for debugging.

```
array1 = (x..y).to_a
array1.each do |n|

  if PrimeFun.primelogic(n%60, n) == 1
    array1.delete_if { |p| p % n == 0}
```

`array1.each` is more or less

```
for(index = 0; index < array1.length; ++i)
```

but when you remove the multiples of `n`, you also remove `n` itself, so the element directly after moves to the index `n` had, and is skipped. You can fix that by deleting only multiples of `n` greater than `n`:

```
array1.delete_if { |p| p > n && p % n == 0 }
```

---

### Performance

The big performance problem is the algorithm. If you call `initialize(2,n)`, for every prime, you traverse the array and remove multiples by trial division. Each prime is divided by each smaller prime (except 2, 3 and 5) to see whether it shall be removed from the array. That is the infamous Turner "sieve" whose complexity is O((n/log n)^2), almost quadratic. Since you don't even remove multiples of 2,3 and 5 from the array unless these multiples have larger prime factors, the complexity might be even slightly worse.

Micro-optimisations simply aren't worth the effort before you pick a better algorithm.

The next problem is the determination of primality using `formulaX`. If you also removed multiples of 2, 3 and 5 from the array, the test wouldn't even be necessary, every considered number would be a known prime per trial division. Since you don't, checking the candidate for divisibility by 2, 3 or 5 would be much faster than `primelogic`.

`primelogic` uses the logic also used for the Atkin sieve to determine primality, but it tests every number in isolation, therefore testing each number `n` is O(√n). Computing the square root is far more complicated than a division, hence that takes longer than a prime test by trial division.

Comment: Thank you very much - yes, this was my attempt at using the Atkin sieve to determine primality - I appreciate the time you have taken to find the errors in this =). Unfortunately - my mathematical background isn't up to standard (I'm not really a programmer, it's just a hobby I picked up recently) so I'm still working on that side of it. I'm familiar with big O notation (I saw it on wikipedia) when I was reading about algorithm scalability (linear vs binary search algorithms) but I honestly don't understand it or how it is used very well - I'll go read up on it and try harder to understand! =)